# What is the meaning of a big "V" in measure theory?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to understand random variables and I came across [this](http://math.mit.edu/%7Edws/175/prob01.pdf):

> As will become increasing evident as we proceed, infinite families of independent objects possess surprising and beautiful properties. In particular, mutually
> independent σ-algebras tend to fill up space in a sense which is made precise by
> the following beautiful thought experiment designed by A.N. Kolmogorov. Let
> I be any index set, take $F_∅ = \{∅, Ω\},$ and for each nonempty subset $Λ ⊆ I,$ let
>
> $$\mathcal F_\Lambda = \bigvee \mathcal F_i \equiv \sigma \left(\bigcup_{i\in \mathcal I} \mathcal F_i \right)$$
>
> be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in \Lambda} \mathcal F_i,$ (i.e., $\mathcal F_\Lambda$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in \Lambda} \mathcal F_i$).

The probability that I understand this anytime soon is zero almost surely, but to begin with, I would like to get what

```
\\\$\big vee $:
```

$\bigvee$

means.

Comment: Perhaps the symbol is defined to be the sigma algebra generated by $\bigcup_{i\in \Lambda}\mathcal{F}_i$?

Comment: @AlekosRobotis I see that. So you are saying that this is not a symbol universally accepted in math, but rather a symbol introduced for the notational expediency of the paper?

Comment: I don't study probability theory, so I'm not really able to say whether or not this is standard notation. But it's quite possible this is what the author means.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis Thank you very much. I bet you are right. It is just unfamiliar and a bit intimidating to have two names for the same idea: $\mathcal F_\Lambda$ and $\bigvee \mathcal F_i.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following up on my comment above. It appears as though the definition is that
$$
\bigvee_{i\in \Lambda}\mathcal{F}_i=\text{The Sigma Algebra Generated by the Sets }\mathcal{F}_i
$$
based on the context.

$\S2.3 $ of the following wikipedia article agrees with this: [Wikipedia: $\sigma$-algebra.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Combining_%CF%83-algebras)

Comment: Thanks, man! Good karma to you for spelling out in English what for you must be like baby talk given your profile. Not the norm!

Comment: Happy to help. I'm pretty sure that people get confused about unexplained notations at any and every level. Good luck!